# Simulator in use XCode 7

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, alert, xcode7

I have facing this issue frequently, and would like to fix permanently. There are a few known solutions I have like reset the simulator or quitting. But is there a proper fix?

[image: Simulator in Use]

Comment: The fix is Don't Do That. If the simulator is in use by one project, don't try to launch it with another project.

Answer (score 0):

You can run only one application on simulator at one time, So you can used below steps for resolve your problem as:-
A. Quit all other application and run simulator.
Or
B. Quit simulator and re-start application.
Or
C. Reset simulator or derived data based on your requirement.

Answer (score -1):

**Simple SoLution** My friend

> 1. First of all **quit your simulator**.
> 2. And then **quit and restart Xcode**.
> 3. And then **run your project**.

it will work like Smoothly. try once.. its working 100 %

Then after it does't Work then

> **Try doing a reset content and settings**

[image]

Another Way,

**If you have two projects open in Xcode and one is running on the simulator, you can't run the other. Go through each project window and see if any are running, and if they are, press the "Stop" button on the top left**

Another Way

[multiple-projects-using-the-simulator](http://multiple-projects-using-the-simulator) then Here is the p[erfect answer, you can use ot. might be helpful to you.

Comment: Reset Content and Settings... would have no effect on this issue.